# SDL 8.5 Auto Deploying CMS items to higher Environment- Item Sync Utility

Tags: web8.5, content-manager, content-porter-2013

We want to automate build process, we can do code build automation, but still we have to manually port Tridion Content items from one environment to another environment using content porter, Do we have any utility which will sync all CMS Items(Path Configurable) to disk which can be source control and on another environment, and with code build we will sync back all items to different Tridion CMS instance.

Please let us know if any such utility exist.

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Answer (score 2):

One of our Community members build DTAP-It, decribed here http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.nl/2015/06/dtap-it.html which is quite a step in the right direction you are looking for it seems.

It unfortunately seems that his GitHub repository is unavailable due to DMCA takedown, so I guess you need to contact Jaime for that and see if it can be sorted.